# issues importing c++ class

Tags: c++, linux

I have a class A(has a.h and a.cpp file) which I am importing to main.cpp. I created an object of the class A and trying to access the methods in class I get undefined reference to `A::Reset(unsigned int*, unsigned int*)'.

I am not sure whats wrong in my code

//a.h

```
#ifndef _A_H_
#define _A_H_

class A
{

    public:

        A();
        void Reset();
};
#endif
```

//a.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"

A::A()
{

    Reset();
}


void A::Reset()
{

}
```

//main.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    A *aObj = new A;
    aObj->Reset();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it's `A* aObj = new A;`. `new` returns pointer.

Comment: `_A_H_` is [bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: What compilation commands are you using? And "import" is not the right wording for C++ ....

Comment: It gives me command not found.

Answer (score 3):

Correct you main.cpp file as this:

```
#include "a.h" 

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    A *aObj = new A; 
    aObj->Reset();

/*
or
   A aObj;
   aObj.Reset()
*/
}
```

Comment: Sorry it was a copy mistake. I had a star.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to compile and link both `A.cpp` and `main.cpp` when building the executable. For example:

```
g++ -o main A.cpp main.cpp
```

As to the missing `compare()` function, make sure that it's declared in `A.h`:

```
class A {
   ...
   int compare(unsigned int*, unsigned int*);
}
```

and defined in `A.cpp`:

```
int A::compare(unsigned int*, unsigned int*) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: He does not need to include a.cpp file

Comment: It should be `g++ -g -Wall a.cpp main.cpp -o main`